# MySql Insert if not exist

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I want to add a row to my MySql table only if it's not exist in the table wi this command:

```
INSERT INTO client.viewcount (clientid, userid)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '1111111', '222') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT clientid,userid FROM client.viewcount WHERE clientid = '1111111' AND userid = '222'
) LIMIT 1;
```

It's work and insert only if it's not exist in the table.
The issue i have another table

```
Users

id    userid    viewcount
1     123456    45
2     987741    62
3     741369    20
```

And i want to be able to increase the `viewcount` of a user.
Something like :
if i add

```
(clientid,userid) => (a432543,123456) 
If it's not exist in the table => Insert and increase the viewcount to 46.
```

Can i implement it in the one commend?

Comment: Do you want to only insert if the SELECT clientid,userid FROM client.viewcount WHERE clientid = '1111111' AND userid = '222' returns no rows right? Your SQL very difficult to follow.

Comment: @Onam I want to add only if this clientid and user id don't exist and increase the viewcount in the user table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UserTable WHERE clientid = @clientid  AND userid = @userid )
BEGIN
    UPDATE ViewcountTable SET viewcount = viewcount+1
    WHERE clientid = @clientid  AND userid = @userid;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO UserTable (clientid, userid);
      INSERT INTO ViewcountTable (userid, 0);
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the 'replace into' can help you: it inserts (or updates if the record already exists).

Comment: The command i insert already insert if not exist, but i want to increase the viewcount in another table too.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried this so might be couple of errors (don't have tables to try this on) but should work.

```
DECLARE @viewcount INT;
SET @viewcount = 0;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT clientid,userid FROM client.viewcount WHERE clientid = @clientid AND userid = @userid)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO client.viewcount (clientid, userid)
    VALUES (@clientid, @userid)

    SELECT @viewcount = viewcount FROM [Users] WHERE clientid = @clientid  AND userid = @userid
    SET @viewcount = @viewcount + 1;
    UPDATE [Users] SET viewcount = @viewcount
    WHERE clientid = @clientid  AND userid = @userid 
END
```

Comment: Essentially, check if row exists if it doesn't insert it. Then get the viewcount (via select @viewcount) increment it and update it.